# Why was my answer to a question deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I posted some additional information on a topic that appeared to be the same as mine.  It included additional information but also ended in a question, since I had not found a complete answer to the issue in my search.

The deleted answer was part of this question: [How can I install zipruby under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12845506/396458)
Please advise on this.

Also it would be nice if there was a clear place that directed newer users to the Meta Stack Overflow to answer questions like this.  I was unaware of this protocol and didn't find anything in the FAQ that seemed to indicate I had posted improperly.

Comment: item 10204665? What do you mean? You mean this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204665/how-can-i-install-zipruby-under-windows

Comment: Yes, my answer to that question.

Comment: Your answer seems to just be a bunch of 'additional information', and not really an answer at all. Stack Exchange tends to look for clear, on-topic, pointed answers to the specific question being asked.

Comment: I have updated your question to reflect that. Please include such links yourself next time. It makes things a bit easier to follow for us.

Comment: @Bart - Thanks for fixing my request.  I am relatively new to the site, so wasn't sure the best way to reference the original issue.  Would it be best if I asked this as a new question?  I am still searching for the answer to installing ZipRuby on a Windows 7 platform using the MingGW distro of Ruby. It is not clear from the original question if the poster is looking for exactly the same thing or not. Sorry for the newbie errors.

Comment: Additional information is not an answer.  If you don't have an answer, stick to comments.  Apart from anything else, you're much less likely to be deleted/voted down.

Answer (score 10):

Your deleted 'answer' was deleted because it is not, in fact, an answer.  It was flagged as `not an answer` and deleted by a moderator because they agreed with the flag.

If you have a question, use the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link.

In your case, you had the same issue as the OP, and spent about 95% of your considerably long post explaining your own problem, with the 5% in the end saved for what *looks* to be an answer.  At best, the rest of your post should be deleted and moved to an actual question (if there's still a question you need answering), and the last paragraph should stand.

Once you've made those improvements to your question, flag it for undeletion and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: You are correct it was not an answer.  If the OP is in fact dealing with ZipRuby on Widows that is running mingw Ruby, the additional information could be helpful. But should have been placed in a comment and not added as an answer.  I have opened my own inquiry since I still do need an answer and it is not clear if we are both really working on the same issue.  The gem is the same, we are both on Windows but the Ruby platform makes all the difference in this case.  I will also reach out in a comment to see if the OP has resolved this or not.